# How to generate more than one pdf from a node?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I need to generate two or more PDF from the same node with different templates.
e.g.: from a reservation page of a accomodations site I would generate a PDF for client, a PDF for owner and a PDF for agent

I'm currently using Print module.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print module doesn't support choosing multiple templates and content from the page. You'd have to create a custom module for that which isn't a trivial task.

If you can't code, maybe you can restructure your Reservation page in a way to use different Content types that reference each other (Entity reference). One CT for client info, the other for owner info and a third one for agent info.

You can use Views to display all that info on one page, all together. But Print module would apply to each node separately, so you'd be able to have that separate.

It may be that info you want to show overlaps between PDFs. You'd have to come up with a custom solution for anything more complicated like that.

Maybe you can combine different solutions for different PDFs.

Check out [Entity Print](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print), [Printing any Drupal Entity to PDF](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/printing-any-drupal-entity-pdf).